# Needing help creating a function which returns true when n is divisible by 11

Tags: python

I'm currently working on a problem which requires me to return true if n is divisible by 11 without using the division or modulous operator.

It's mentioned that if we add and subtract the digits alternatively and it adds up to be 0, -11 or 11 it means that it is divisible by 11:

Example1: 121
1 - 2 + 1 = 0

Example 2: 509
3 - 5 + 0 - 9 = -11

Both of these are divisible by 11.

Currently I have this for my code.

```
def div_11(n):
    alternative = (sum(n[0::2])) 
    second_alternative = (sum(n[1::2]))

    if (alternative1 - alternative2) % 11 == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

I was hoping that for alternative, I would have the second, fourth, sixth, etc value in a list, and for second_alternative, I would have the first, third, fifth, etc value. With that, I would do alternative subtracted by the second_alternative divided by 11, and if it returned 0 I would deem that as true.

My error comes from saying the int object is not subscriptable. Does anyone have any solutions?

This is the test code we are given:

```
    nlst = [587657752,11,22,2728,31415,1358016]
    for n in nlst:
        print(div_11(n), n / 11)
```

I have tried subtracting the alternative and the second_alternative to return 0 which I believe would make it divisible by 11, however I received a Type:Error which said int subscript is not subscriptable.

Comment: First off, you can't slice an int. Convert it to a string first, then convert the components back to ints for the mathematical operations. Second, you say you can't use the modulus operator, yet it's in your function on the third line...

Comment: You need to repeat the process until the result is a single digit. Then, the number is divisible by 11 if and only if that single digit is 0.

Comment: Don't want to dress you down here, but this question is not really useful. Editing it to its current state, it cannot even be answered and existing answers no longer show a reference to what could have been asked in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

That happens because you're trying to slice an integer, not a list.

You can solve this problem by changing the integer to a list, and then try using slicing.
This can be done by the code below.

```py
listNum = list(map(int, str(num)))
```

use this `listNum` instead of `n` in your code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to repeat the process until the result is a single digit.

Then, the number is divisible by 11 if and only if that single digit is 0.

For example:

```
def div_11(n):
    while n > 9:
        s = str(n)
        x = sum([int(s[i]) for i in range(0,len(s),2)]) # sum of digits in even places
        y = sum([int(s[i]) for i in range(1,len(s),2)]) # sum of digits in odd places
        n = abs(x - y) # just in case the intermediate result is negative
    return n == 0
```

Comment: In order to support negative input as well, you can add `n = abs(n)` at the beginning of the function.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing an integer to the function, which can't be sliced. The passed number should be a string in order to pick the alternative digits using slicing.

Furthermore, you're still using the modulus operator to determine the divisibility by 11, which can be replaced by a look-up inside a list.

Try the following:

```
def div_11(n):
    n = str(n)
    alternative = sum(int(digit) for digit in n[::2]) 
    second_alternative = sum(int(digit) for digit in n[1::2])

    if (alternative - second_alternative) in [-11, 0, 11]:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```